# "If I am getting late"

Tags: tenses

Is it correct to say "If I am getting late, I will let you know"? The Conditional rules don't say anything about continuous tense. In addition, what would be a better way of conveying the same message?

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong with using the continuous tense here. The reason your example sounds odd to native English speakers is that the idiom you want is *"running late"* rather than *"getting late"*. We use *"getting late"* to mean that time has been passing, and the hour of the day is becoming late. We use *"running late"* to say that somebody (or something) is behind in their schedule. For instance:

> It's getting late. I should go home now; we can finish this tomorrow.
>
> I'm running late. Can we meet at 12:30 rather than noon?

So the correct way of phrasing your sentence is:

> If I am running late, I will let you know.

Comment: Some people might use: if I was getting late, I will late you know. Is this also correct?

Comment: The tenses are wrong in that sentence. I can't say what it should be, since I don't quite know what you're trying to say. *"If I were running late, I would have let you know"* is one possibility.

Comment: You are right it sounds strange. I am trying to talk about a future event. Does your example talk about a past or future possibility?

Comment: With a future event, you need to use *"am running late"*. My example talks about a present hypothetical event.

Comment: Shouldn't the second part of your  example be " simple past"  instead of the " present perfect"?

Comment: Good question. It does disobey the strict rules of the three conditionals as taught in ESL, but as a native speaker, I think it sounds fine. I think the rules for conditionals are more complicated, and there are more possibilities, if you use a continuous tense, but I don't know what they are.

Comment: Cool. Because I had  been using the same structure in my day to day conversation until I read about this rule.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to say:

> If I'm going to be late, I will let you know.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn´t use the continuous tense when you inform a person about a possible delay .. in this case "If I am late I will let you know " will do :) If you still want to stress the continuous action use the verb RUN instead of GET which may sound better " In case I am running late I will let you know well in advance"

Comment: I am not the Queen of English grammar still I think continuous tense is not that frequent to use in there. As for "I would have let you know" this is the third conditional depicting an action done in the past which you cannot take back because it has already happened using past perfect in the first part of the sentence and would + present perfect in the second" If I had seen her picture I would have never invited her for a picnic . "